# GKE: when deleting unused managed certificate, it reapears a few moments later

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to delete some managed certificates that are seemingly unused, but when I delete them they are recreated automatically.
These certificates seem to be copies of a certificate that I am actually using, they have the same DNS (the ones marked in red) but they allways stay on provisioning status.
Here is an image, if it helps.[The certificates, censored for privacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojdhi.png)

I've already tried using the "delete" button in this page, gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete [NAME], which both deleted the certificates, but they later reapeared.

Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: the certificates is question:
[Functional certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpWI9.png),
[Broken certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebCAe.png)

Comment: Can you run this command inside your cluster?

kubectl delete managedcertificates <certificate-name>

Comment: @OnlyJams thanks for the reply! I tried what you suggested and it returned this error: Error from server (NotFound): managedcertificates.networking.gke.io "[NAME]" not found. I used the name found in the "Name" column, is this right?

Comment: Do you have a GKE cluster in that project which uses Google Managed Certificate ? You have to check all the clusters !

Comment: @Lynx I see. I am under the assumption that those are Google Managed Certificates. In that case, can you try to remove the ManagedCertificate object and the Ingress annotation that references it. Please try the command:

kubectl delete -f managed-cert.yaml and
kubectl annotate ingress managed-cert-ingress networking.gke.io/managed-certificates-

Comment: @Lynx you may use the link for reference:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#removing_a_google-managed_certificate

Comment: @OnlyJams thanks for the tips, but i believe all 3 of the certificates where somehow created from the same yaml, as that is the only one I used, and I fear that using the commands suggested would delete the correct one. Now, that wouldn't be too big of a problem as I generate it again but still.  I'm including two images of the "right" and "wrong" certificates, hope they are useful. (I've edited the post to include them, as I couldn't figure out how to put one in a comment)

Comment: @Lynx Unfortunately, it will be very difficult to provide at the very least. accurate recommendation without looking at the specific ingress yaml files. What I can suggest for now is to look into the Ingress yaml and remove the annotations of the certificate that you wish to remove (networking.gke.io/managed-certificates-<certificate-name-to-be-deleted>)then save, and then manifest the ingress yaml file once again.

Comment: Okay, I figured out what the problem was when I was deleting the ingress (which still only had the right certificate there).  While I was deleting the "certificate" in the certificates tab of Network services, I noticed that even without the ingress it was still regenerating.  Turns out that the files themselves for the certificates weren't actually getting deleted in the object browser, so I made some quick yamls with the names there and kubectl deleted them.  Thank you @OnlyJams for the help.